# Is there a way to check for a working polkit agent without checking for running process?

Tags: polkit

I need to check if I have an usable polkit agent in a desktop-environment agnostic way.

Right now, what I'm doing is to check if a polkit agent is running, using a code like this:

```
ps aux | grep some-polkit-agent
```

where `some-polkit-agent` may be:

- `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` (for gnome2 and gnome3-fallback)
- `polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1` (for kde)
- `polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1` (for mate)
- `lxpolkit` (for lxde)

The "no-fallback" gnome3 (gnome-shell) has its own polkit agent within the gnome-shell process itself, so I can't ps-grep it. What I assume is that if `gnome-shell` is running then the polkit agent is in place.

The problem comes when a system has `hidepid` enabled (see http://www.linux-dev.org/2012/09/hide-process-information-for-other-users/).
This security measure makes that a `ps` doesn't show me any polkit agent running even if there is one.

Is there any better way that I can check for an usable polkit agent?

Comment: `pkexec command` will run `command` with sudo privileges. It'll give a popup asking to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to check if I have an usable polkit agent"

Presumably you want it to be usable for a specific process, either a process pid or since you cannot see pids, a system bus name?

In that case you could use "pkcheck" for the specific process and check its return value because the manual page for pkcheck says

```
   If the specificied process is not authorized because **no suitable**
   **authentication agent is available** or if the --allow-user-interaction
   wasn't passed, pkcheck exits with a return value of 2 and a diagnostic
   message is printed on standard error. Details are printed on standard
   output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Agents register themselves to the polkit authority over dbus. If you could intercept their dbus traffic you would know exactly what agent is registered.

Comment: How would intercepting their dbus traffic be done?

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211822), you need to install the `policykit-desktop-privileges` package.

Comment: I don't need/want to install a polkit agent. I need a way to know if there is a polkit agent running.